# How to handle failures in AWS cloudformation CUSTOM resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I Have a lambda function created using CFN which looks like this:

```
InitializeDynamoDBLambda:   
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile:  |          
          const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
          const response = require("cfn-response");
          const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
              let DynamoTableName = event.ResourceProperties.DynamoTable;
              let KeyJSON = JSON.parse(event.ResourceProperties.KeyJSON);
              let ValueJSON = JSON.parse(event.ResourceProperties.ValueJSON);

              for(key in KeyJSON){
              var params = {
                  TableName: DynamoTableName,
                  Item: {
                      'Key': KeyJSON[key],
                      'Value': JSON.stringify(ValueJSON[key])
                  }
              };
              docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
                  if (err) {
                      console.log(err);                    
                      response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, {});
                  }
                  else {
                      response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {});
                  }
              });
              }
          };          
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaExecutionRole.Arn'
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Timeout: 60
```

This Lambda is initialized using a `CUSTOM` resource like this:

```
InitializeDB:
    Type: Custom::InitializeDynamoDBLambda
    Properties:
        ServiceToken:
            Fn::GetAtt: [ InitializeDynamoDBLambda , "Arn" ]
        DynamoTable: !Ref TenantLevelDBname
        KeyJSON: !Ref KeyJSON
        ValueJSON: !Ref ValueJSON
```

The problem is when there is an error, the Cloudformation stack gets stuck in a state like UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS etc.

How do I handle failures in such scenarios?

Comment: Best guess is that one of the things that's not contained within a try/catch is throwing. Have you looked at the log output on CloudWatch? Wrapping the entire function body in a try/catch might be a good place to start debugging. I'd also log the contents of `event`, to ensure that I'm getting what I expect. Lastly, you should probably restructure that loop (and indent it properly) so that you're not sending a response every time through.